# Accept date input (datepicker) whether the user inputs full date or only year or only year&month

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am still new and still exploring somehow i did not see any solution to my problem please be kind :)

I am using codeigniter framework

Here is my code from my form that gets the date:

```
//user input in my view
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="date">

//get value using post in my conntroller
$date => $_POST["date"];
```

I want it to accept value even if the user inputs year only or year&month only.

For example the format of the date picker is mm/dd/yyy

then if the user only inputs mm/dd/1993 or 12/dd/1997

i want it to still accept it and be saved to the database

Comment: Just to be clear - what do you mean by "accept", here? The datepicker is a front-end component, and *accepting* input there is different from accepting it server-side. Thanks in advance for any clarifications you add to the Q! Also, welcome to SO!

Comment: what i mean is when i input year only (mm/dd/1993 - which is invalid) it becomes 0000-00-00 in my database. So i want it to ignore the date format validation to appear like 1993-00-00 in my database. Thanks for giving attention to my question

Comment: Hey, @abegail___, this is what I mean by not being accepted on the front-end. When I submit this, it never reaches the server. https://i.imgur.com/9peMeq7.jpg

Comment: yes that is exactly what is shows. But how can i change the validation so it would accept that kind of input?